# comprehension list vs for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have written a simple program that will take the first letter of a string and capitalize it.

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()
    a=[word[0].upper() for word in words]
    b = '. '.join(a) + '.'
    return b
text = "have a good day sir"

print(initials(text))
```

This will give me the result i want by using a list comprehension.
however i cannot make it work by using a typical FOR LOOP as below and it will give me only the last iteration:

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        a=word[0].upper()
        b = '.'.join(a) + '.'
    return b
text = "have a good day sir"

print(initials(text))
```

any idea why the second example doesn't work as the first one?

Comment: Because in your second `initials` function, `b` is updated for each word in `words`... You don't "keep track" of the previous initials.

Comment: You need to add results to a new list, then pass to `join`

Comment: write `a += word[0].upper()` and take the statement `b='.'.join(a) + '.'` out of the for-loop

Answer (score 2):

`b` is being reset every time around the loop in the second case. So you only get the last initial followed by `.`. The equivalent to your comprehension in a `for` loop, would be:

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()
    a = []
    for word in words:
        a.append(word[0].upper())
    b = '.'.join(a) + '.'
    return b
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting b on each loop iteration. Try:

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        a = word[0].upper()
        b += '.'.join(a) + '.'
    return b
text = "have a good day sir"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `str.join()` takes a iterable of strings, but in your second function you are passing a single chararacter. The fact that you are calling it inside the loop does not convert it into a list of characters.

The easiest way for you is to get rid of the `str.join()` and use a simple string to accumulate the result:

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()
    b = ''
    for word in words:
        a=word[0].upper()
        b += a + '.'
    return b
```

If you insist in using `str.join()` you will need a list to accumulate your initials:

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()
    b = []
    for word in words:
        a=word[0].upper()
        b.append(a)
    return '.'.join(b) + '.'
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `char` type in Python, there are just strings of length 1.